# How do I define a block of a $(0,1)$-matrix as one that has no proper sub-blocks?

Tags: matrices, definition

I'm struggling to come up with a definition of a "block" in a $(0,1)$-matrix $M$ such that we can decompose $M$ into blocks, but the blocks themselves don't further decompose.  This is what I've got so far:

> Given any $r \times s$ $(0,1)$-matrix $M$, we define a *block* of $M$ to be a submatrix $H$ in which: (a) every row and every column of $H$ contains a $1$, (b) in $M$, there are no $1$'s in the rows of $H$ outside of $H$, (c) in $M$, there are no $1$'s in the columns of $H$ outside of $H$, and (d) no proper submatrix of $H$ satisfies (a)-(c).

I want to define blocks in such a way that there are no proper sub-blocks in blocks.  But I feel item (d) is difficult to parse.  I can't just say "there's no proper sub-blocks" because this is a circular definition.

> **Q**: Could the community suggest a better way of phrasing this definition?

My conundrum reminds me of this comic:

[image: But *I* know what I mean!]

Comment: Between this and your profile, it seems you have excellent taste in comics

Comment: I’m perfectly happy with it as it stands. I don’t object to **Omnomnomnom**’s suggestion, but I don’t see it as an actual improvement.

Comment: The downside of Omnomnomnom's suggestion is it introduces an auxiliary definition, which I won't need elsewhere.  The trouble I see with "no proper submatrix of $H$ satisfies (a)-(c)" is that when using (a)-(c) for $H$, we need to have $H$ becoming the new $M$, and some unnamed submatrix becoming the new $H$, but the reader might interpret $H$ as staying as $H$ and be confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest breaking this up into two definitions... maybe call one of them a "block", and another a "simple block".  That is:

> Given any $r \times s$ $(0,1)$-matrix $M$, we define a *block* of $M$ to be a submatrix $H$ in which: (a) every row and every column of $H$ contains a $1$, (b) in $M$, there are no $1$'s in the rows of $H$ outside of $H$, (c) in $M$, there are no $1$'s in the columns of $H$ outside of $H$.
>
> A sub-block of a block $H$ is a block $J$ of the submatrix $H$.  If $J \neq H$, then $J$ is a *proper* sub-block.
>
> We say that $H$ is a *simple block* if it has no proper sub-block.

How's that? Alternatively, call the first one a "pre-block", and the second a "block" (cf. pre-sheaf vs. sheaf).

Comment: I think that's what I'm going to have to do.  Thanks.